# Is there an advantage of having a single google console API project for different apps/usage?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-play-services, google-console-developer

What is the benefit of having different projects (console) than having a single project for all your different apps.

i.e

I have one project that is used for googlesheet auto update
I have another project that is used for google email automation
I have another project for scripting google Maps

vs a single project that is used for the sheet autoupdate, email automation and maps api.

Are the apps sharing quota limits?

Answer (score 1):

The bigest thing in my opinion is the consent screen.   When you request access from a user you are requesting access as an application

[image]

Now in this instance Google Oauth 2.0 playground would like permission to access my data.  As a user i would assume then that only Google Oauth 2.0 playground would be accessing my data and not Super awesome other application under the same project.

Second issue will be quota.  A number of the quotas are project based.   So if you have a max of 50000 requests that the project can make and you have two different applications using with well.   You are going to run out of quota twice as fast.